# Can you save an animated gif using UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimage, animated-gif

I have a function to create a gif out of an array of UIImages. I can check the count and it is 32 images. I think the thing I'm doing wrong is that I'm converting the URL data back into a UIImage which only saves the first frame. I'd rather save the image right from the URL, but I'm not familiar with any way of doing that except with saving an AVAsset from video.

```
func createGIF(with images: [UIImage], loopCount: Int = 0, frameDelay: Double) {
    let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: loopCount]]
    let frameProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: frameDelay]]

    let documentsDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("myAnimatedGIF.gif")

    let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(url! as CFURL, kUTTypeGIF, Int(images.count), nil)
    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination!, fileProperties as CFDictionary)

    print(images.count)
    for i in 0..<images.count {
        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination!, images[i].cgImage!, frameProperties as CFDictionary)
    }

    if CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination!) {           
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)

        if data != nil {
            print("saved gif")
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image!, self, #selector(addImageToLibrary(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)

        }


    } else {
        print("failed")
    }
}
```

To save the gif from the URL, I've tried:

```
let image = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

ALAssetsLibrary().writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, metadata: nil, completionBlock: { (assetURL: NSURL!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                    print(assetURL)
                })
```

but I get the error "Ambiguous use of 'init(contentsOfURL:)'", and I don't know the way of doing this in Swift 4.

Comment: Swift3 and later you should use `Data` initializer `Data(contentsOf: URL)` instead of `NSData`. But for loading data from non local resource urls you should use `URLSession` `dataTask(with: URL)` method to download it asynchronously. Btw the same applies to NSURL. You should drop the NS prefix and use `URL` initializers.

Comment: Hey! did you found any solution?

Comment: So many things changed since I posted this, but check out CustomPhotoAlbum by ChanWarde: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666929/how-to-create-custom-album-in-swift-3-ios-10